# cryptojs.AES.encrypt from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I have the following string `test/2023/01/03/542-0900909090-03012023-123456-0123456789.2263.wav`

Now I want to encrypt in PHP by using `cryptojs.AES.encrypt` in Javascript

I have  search everything but it seems not working.

PHP:

```php
$content_url = "test/2023/01/03/542-0900909090-03012023-123456-0123456789.2263.wav" ;
$private_key = "13245678901";
$method = "AES-256-CBC";
$encrypt_url = openssl_encrypt($content_url,$method,$private_key);
print_r($url);
exit;

//DkHbuRH5HsbXaHagSLLT2Fa2RWY9kebvll8zASSlu97ksCPg197h8HDdriKZJ86aZ1tx9g9HTR7NxEEyZgKdJ9hHopVgaPC2DdjJmOCC3R0=
```

Javascript:

```js
let strEncrypt = "test/2023/01/03/542-0900909090-03012023-123456-0123456789.2263.wav"
let private_key = "13245678901";
let url = cryptojs.AES.encrypt(encodeURIComponent (strEncrypt), private_key)
console.log(url)

//U2FsdGVkX19dQBJ1JKLZlRhznvVf5E3X8ts6n2l3mBZhRhGh0b2DZQdupehdZpcYq3PDZPSGLdXbmI9Ud027TYbpD3QM+mYr/2LSIXiLquEToZZ/Lq+Qg6tVt7AbQjwt
```

The result is not the same when I decrypt it.

in javascript have `encodeURIComponent`, do PHP have something like this function?

Comment: `the result is not the same` what result is not the same as what? you've shown no output

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` has f-all to do with encryption

Comment: Please show how you are using `encodeURIComponent`. PHP has functions similiar but your code doesn't appear to be using that currently.  There is https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: crypto can be confusing between different languages ... some expect keys/content in particular formats for example, I tried duplicating your JS code and got a completely different result, perhaps I used [CryptoJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js) and that's not `cryptojs` ... dunno

Comment: I have update code where to use  encodeURIComponen

Comment: well, look at `strEncrypt` vs `encodeURIComponent(strEncrypt)` - why would they encrypt to the same value

Comment: So you change the value entirely before encrypting... `openssl_encrypt(urlencode($content_url),$method,$private_key);` (although I would not encode before encrypting).

Comment: try running your JS code more than once to see the futility

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Why do you want to encode the path to a file? How is it protecting the data? How will you retrieve it since it will be encrypted? Why don't you do encryption only on the PHP side?

Comment: On the AES side you use an invalid key size (AES-256 expects a 32 bytes key and not an 11 bytes key). Also, you apply CBC, but don't specify an IV. PHP fixes this silently (pads the key, uses a zero IV), which CryptoJS does not. So, the codes are incompatible. Apply a valid AES key and a valid IV (16 bytes).

Comment: Also, the key material is passed as a string in the CryptoJS code, so CryptoJS applies its built-in key derivation, which generates a completely different key and IV. Pass the key as `WordArray` and explicitly specify the IV (where key and IV must correspond to the values used for encryption of course).

Answer (score 3):

Note that your PHP code does not return the posted ciphertext (also, `$url` is not defined, probably `$encrypt_url` is meant). The correct ciphertext for the posted plaintext and key is:

```
Ppx9QcDN52Xt6vKhpAB40JBWpLNOrSHA7GxpF/GxdlI7mZu4+kqGHtdMRzbCZ8oNxDRUjaojiR9IKIhwakJCOD5TClS3G7z+eQ1T0ml5MnI=
```

*Issues on the PHP side:* The PHP code specifies AES-256-CBC. AES-256 requires a 32 bytes key, while you use an 11 bytes key invalid for AES. Also, the CBC mode requires an IV while you don't specify one.
PHP/OpenSSL silently fixes these shortcomings: A too small key is padded with 0x00 values to the required size. As IV a zero IV is applied (an IV consisting of only 0x00 values; for AES, the IV must be 16 bytes).
On the CryptoJS side these fixes are not performed implicitly, i.e. they have to be done explicitly.

*Issues on the CryptoJS side:* The key material is passed as string. In this case, CryptoJS applies its built-in key derivation, interprets the key material as password and derives a 32 bytes key and 16 bytes IV from it so that a completely different key and IV are used than on the PHP side.
In order for the key material to be interpreted as key, it must be passed as WordArray. In addition, the IV must be explicitly specified (as WordArray).

The following CryptoJS code generates the same ciphertext as the PHP code:

```js
let strEncrypt = "test/2023/01/03/542-0900909090-03012023-123456-0123456789.2263.wav"
let private_key = "13245678901";

let privateKeyWA = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(private_key); // 1. convert the key material to a WordArray, so that it's interpreted as key
privateKeyWA = privateKeyWA.concat(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('\0'.repeat(32 - privateKeyWA.sigBytes))); // 2. pad the 11 bytes key with 0x00 values to 32 bytes for AES-256
let iVWA = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('\0'.repeat(16)); // 3. apply a 16 bytes zero IV (as WordArray)

let url = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(strEncrypt, privateKeyWA, {iv: iVWA}) // 4. encrypt (using the default values: CBC and PKCS#7 padding)
console.log(url.toString()) // Ppx9QcDN52Xt6vKhpAB40JBWpLNOrSHA7GxpF/GxdlI7mZu4+kqGHtdMRzbCZ8oNxDRUjaojiR9IKIhwakJCOD5TClS3G7z+eQ1T0ml5MnI=
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

---

Keep in mind that a static IV is a vulnerability. The common way is to generate a random IV during encryption. This is not secret and is passed to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext, usually concatenated: iv|ciphertext.

Also, of course, a valid AES key should be used in the PHP code. This is typically a *random* byte sequence (32 bytes for AES-256).
If you really want to use a passphrase like `13245678901`, a key derivation function (at least PBKDF2) should be applied in conjunction with a randomly generated salt for each encryption.

---

**EDIT:** Porting JavaScript/CryptoJS to PHP/OpenSSL:

In the CryptoJS code, the key material is passed as string, so the key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()` is applied. In PHP, `EVP_BytesToKey()` (or a lightweight version) must be implemented separately. Also, the CryptoJS code generates the ciphertext in the Base64 encoded OpenSSL format: ASCII encoding of Salted__ plus 8 bytes salt plus ciphertext. Because of the constant beginning, the ciphertexts therefore always start with `U2FsdGVkX1`.

For encoding the URI fragment `encodeURIComponent()` is used on the CryptoJS side, on the PHP side `urlencode()` can be applied. The counterparts are `decodeURIComponent()` and `urldecode()`.

In the following the encryption and decryption with the JavaScript code is shown. The decryption is needed to show the compatibility with the PHP code (see below), in that ciphertexts generated with the PHP code can be decrypted with the JavaScript code:

```js
// Encryption
let url = "test/2023/01/03/542-0900909090-03012023-123456-0123456789.2263.wav"
let password = "13245678901"
let url_encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encodeURIComponent(url), password).toString()
console.log(url_encrypted)

// Decryption
let url_decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(url_encrypted, password)
console.log(decodeURIComponent(url_decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)))

// Decryption from ciphertext from PHP side
let url_from_php_encrypted = "U2FsdGVkX1/ubbwT2tjnZ7E6b2Z32N3QkZiwC9H4GQvIwJKPjgIC1XprQDkakua/D2i3qUzGOhGm3ISRam1vDGsZDp+Y+hgz0tNubqgi8Rkcvb4jsUcCLNiedEwt9iZR"
let url_from_php_decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(url_from_php_encrypted, password)
console.log(decodeURIComponent(url_from_php_decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

The counterpart with PHP is:

```php
<?php
function EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $password) {
    $bytes = ''; $last = '';
    while(strlen($bytes) < 48) {
        $last = hash('md5', $last . $password . $salt, true);
        $bytes.= $last;
    }
    return $bytes;
} 

function encrypt($url, $password){
    $method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8);
    $keyIv = EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $password);
    $key = substr($keyIv, 0, 32);
    $iv = substr($keyIv, 32, 16);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(urlencode($url), $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $url_encrypted = base64_encode("Salted__" . $salt . $ciphertext);
    return $url_encrypted;  
}

function decrypt($url_encrypted, $password){
    $method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $url_from_JS_encrypted = base64_decode($url_encrypted);
    $salt = substr($url_from_JS_encrypted, 8, 8);
    $ciphertext = substr($url_from_JS_encrypted, 16);
    $keyIv = EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $password);
    $key = substr($keyIv, 0, 32);
    $iv = substr($keyIv, 32, 16);
    $url_decrypted = urldecode(openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
    return $url_decrypted;  
}

// Encryption
$url = "test/2023/01/03/542-0900909090-03012023-123456-0123456789.2263.wav" ;
$password = "13245678901";
$url_encrypted = encrypt($url, $password);
print($url_encrypted . PHP_EOL);

// Decryption 
$url_decrypted = decrypt($url_encrypted, $password);
print($url_decrypted . PHP_EOL);

// Decryption from ciphertext from JavaScript side
$url_from_JS_encrypted = "U2FsdGVkX1+DXgB83m9WnIxbEPITUj4xsVlUvxMHkDwASqIomYFY6sx5eIX6CaFwv0C2hVEYgLssywexycmfmasGMymy+Aeg/4waeIMpWRE9SgQUsGvmT/zr8tJVnwXE";
$url_from_JS_decrypted = decrypt($url_from_JS_encrypted, $password);
print($url_from_JS_decrypted . PHP_EOL);
?>
```

The implementations are compatible, i.e. ciphertexts encrypted with the JavaScript/CryptoJS code can be decrypted with the PHP/OpenSSL and vice versa.

Comment: Check the ciphertext from the PHP code online here: https://paiza.io/projects/uod0P71GhlS-jlSI87zVAw

Comment: You can put the link to Paiza in the answer, instead of commenting it.

Comment: it i have the serectkey is `ger54Q0BQzLV3b5RVEQXQ8svaDN5p0SRVW8elaWTbMez0` but don't have `IV` and if i have `IV` then will it change anything? , so can i convert the `encrypt_url` to `PHP`?

Comment: @phu.duongquoc - I'm not quite clear what you mean. But on re-reading your question, it seems that you rather need a port from JavaScript/CryptoJS to PHP/OpenSSL. See the edit section of my answer.

Comment: Run the PHP code online here: https://paiza.io/projects/SBYuAD6gl--xvWF7RkQVHA.

Comment: @A.L - I'm posting the link outside my answer because I have no control over how long the link is valid and I want to avoid a dead link in the answer.